# Replacing multiple values with multiple values of a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of country names, say `locations = c("UK", "USA", "US", "United States", "United Kingdom", ...)`. I want to make a substitution where all variants of US gets replaced with US and all variants of UK gets replaced with GB. Other than writing if statementss to check each case, can I supply two vectors, e.g. `originalNames = c("USA", "United States", "US", "United States of America",...)` and `newNames = c("US", "US", "US", "US",...)` where I would instruct R to replace all values of locations found in originalNames by the corresponding positions in newNames?

Comment: Can you show all the variations?  Is that all that you showed in the example?

Comment: In this particular case the `countrycode` package would be helpful. Specifically, `library(countrycode); countrycode(location, 'country.name', 'iso2c')`

Answer (score 2):

Create two vectors, one for each `originalNames` of `US` and `UK` variants.  Then use `gsub()`:

```
us_pattern <- paste(us_newNames, collapse="|");
uk_pattern <- paste(uk_newNames, collapse="|");

locations <- gsub(us_pattern, "US", locations, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE);
locations <- gsub(uk_pattern, "GB", locations, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE);
```

Comment: Incidentally, I agree this strategy is more elegant for the many-to-one case, though doesn't generalize as well for e.g. 1000s of equivalence classes of names. Could combine this with a `Reduce` or `lapply` to good effect.

Answer (score 2):

What about this

```
locations <- c("UK", "USA", "US", "United States", "United Kingdom") 
originalNames <- c("USA", "United States", "United States of America", "United Kingdom")
newNames <- c("US", "US", "US", "UK")
Reduce(function(x,i) gsub(originalNames[i],newNames[i],x),seq_along(originalNames),locations)

> locations <- c("UK", "USA", "US", "United States", "United Kingdom") 
> originalNames <- c("USA", "United States", "United States of America", "United Kingdom")
> newNames <- c("US", "US", "US", "UK")
> Reduce(function(x,i) gsub(originalNames[i],newNames[i],x),seq_along(originalNames),locations)
[1] "UK" "US" "US" "US" "UK"
```

The constraints for this to work are that originalNames and newNames are equal length vectors where `originalNames[i]` should be replaced by `newNames[i]`.

This function makes multiple passes through your vector `locations`, each time doing a substitution in that vector, looking for `originalNames[i]` and replacing it by `newNames[i]`

If you want a faster / more elegant solution that won't make as many passes on a large dataset, you could try something like this:

```
library(data.table)
original.locations <- data.table(locations=c("UK", "USA", "US", "United States", "United Kingdom")) 
replacements <- data.table(originalNames=c("USA", "United States", "United States of America", "United Kingdom"),
newNames=c("US", "US", "US", "UK"))
setkey(original.locations,locations)
setkey(replacements,originalNames)
original.locations[replacements,replacement.name:=i.newNames]
original.locations

    > original.locations
        locations replacement.name
1:             UK               NA
2:             US               NA
3:            USA               US
4: United Kingdom               UK
5:  United States               US
```

(Note here that I didn't specify replacements for "UK" and "US"; you could avoid the NAs by matching them explicitly with themselves.)